# A gambler's fortune converges 0 or 1? (Martingale convergence theorem)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, gambling

Let $ X_0 = 1 , X_n = \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i, \space  (Y_n : nonnegative \space independent, \space E[Y_i]=1) \space \Rightarrow \space then, \space \{X_n\} \space is \space martingale. $

Knowing this, Now let's consider a gambler who bets a fraction ***q*** of his fortune $(0\lt q\lt1)$ with each toss of a fair coin$(p=q=1/2)$ starting with $1.

Let his fortune $ X_n \space after \space n  \space tosses \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + \delta_i\mathbf q), \space where  \space \delta_i = \pm1 \space $

And, ***My textbook*** says that

according to the following Martingale convergence theorem

Let $\{X_n\} \space be \space submartingle \space satisfying \space \space \sup E[|X_n|]\lt\infty\Rightarrow \space then, \space There \space exists \space a \space random \space variable \space X_\infty\space to \space which \space \{X_n\} \space converges \space with \space probability \space one, \space P\{\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X_\infty\}=1$

a gambler's fortune $X_n$,  $\space \sup E[|X_n|] = E[X_n]=1$, so that $\space X_n$ tends to a finite limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, ***which must be ZERO, since every other state is transient.***

I really don't get it at all.  I think it's ***1***(one dolloar) because it's martingale and $E[X_n]=1$ . Why ***ZERO*** ?

Comment: This is an example of a sequence random variables that converges almost surely but does not converge in $L^1$.

Comment: This of course is a consequence of the fact you can not dominate the value of $X_n$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n =\lim_{n\to\infty}exp(nM)=0$ by the strong law of large numbers. However, considering Martingale $E(X_{n+1}) =E(X_n) $, so I still think $E(X_\infty) =E(X_n) = 1$ in some way. Isn't it a contradiction?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know L-norm notation. I only studied some cases where a.s but not convergence in Mean Square. I never thought of convergence in Mean.

Comment: Btw, what do you exactly mean "dominate the value of $X_n$"?

Comment: I believe this example not only a.s but also convergence in mean & mean square, because $E(X^2_n) \le K \le\infty$. There is a theorem saying so. (Martingale & this condition). So, $E(X_0) = E(X_n) = E(X_\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the most extreme case, the gambler bets all of his/her fortune in each step. then $X_n$ is a Martingale that equals $2^n$ with probability $2^{-n}$ and otherwise is zero.  So clearly $X_n$ tends to zero a.s.

To understand the rate of convergence to 0 in the general case,
consider $\log X_n$. It is a sum of $n$ i.i.d. variables, each taking two values, with mean
$$M=\frac{\log(1+q)+\log(1-q)}{2}= \frac{ \log(1-q^2)}{2}<0 \,,$$
so the law of large numbers implies that almost surely
$$\frac 1n \log(X_n) \to M<0 $$
so $X_n =\exp(n(M+o(1)))$ tends to zero exponentially fast.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  What about Martingale perspective? E(Xn) = E(Xn+1)

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n =\lim_{n\to\infty}exp(nM)=0$ by the strong law of large numbers. However, considering Martingale $E(X_{n+1}) =E(X_n) $, so I still think $E(X_\infty) =E(X_n) = 1$ in some way. Isn't it a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Just because $EX_n=1$ and $X_n \to X$ with probability $1$ you cannot say that $X=1$.

I am not sure about the argument in the book but a simple argument shows that $X=0$: If  $\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + \delta_i\mathbf q)  \to X>0$ then $1 + \delta_n\mathbf q =\frac {\prod_{i=1}^n(1 + \delta_i\mathbf q)} {\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (1 + \delta_i\mathbf q)} \to \frac X X =1$. But then $\delta_i\mathbf q \to 0$ which is impossible since $\delta_n =\pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What about Martingale perspective? E(Xn) = E(Xn+1)

Comment: I added the most extreme example of a mean 1 nonnegative martingale that tends to 0.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n =\lim_{n\to\infty}exp(nM)=0$ by the strong law of large numbers. However, considering Martingale $E(X_{n+1}) =E(X_n) $, so I still think $E(X_\infty) =E(X_n) = 1$ in some way. Isn't it a contradiction?

Comment: @DavidLee $\int n I_{(0,\frac 1 n)} =1$ for each $n$ but $n I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}\to 0$. There is no contradiction in this.

Comment: geetha290krm, Yuval Peres,    
  Well, I'm saying " $E(X_\infty) = 1$ " not $E(X_n) = 1$.
There exists some R.V. $\{X_\infty\}$ whose sample space $\{0\}$ or at most  $\{0, 0^+\}$, I think. What distribution, $F_\infty$, can make its mean 1, given that sample space? I think Even a degenerate one makes it's mean 0.